# ViewController pushing to next according to the specific notation

Tags: ios, swift

I need to push and pop the ViewController accordingly, but while pressing back button in my application, the ViewController should switch to next ViewController in backward. I. e. normally by pushing ViewController it slides from right to left, but while clicking back, the ViewController should come from left to right.

I normally use simple presenting and push ViewController codes. Please help me. I don't have navigation controller in my application for some pages and some pages have. Please provide me both solutions.

Comment: its quite unclear.what are you asking?

Comment: you'll have to roll your own custom vc animation, it's not possible to override this default presentation style

Comment: I need when the user press back button from a ViewController, it should move to another viewcontroller by backward sliding style.

Comment: @KARTHICKTM is it going back to actual viewcontroller.

Comment: I need it to going back to the actual view controller where it tapped. @VDPurohit

Comment: @KARTHICKTM can you please try this :-self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true) and another please make sure button has only link with one UIAction

Comment: Working and Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, I am assuming you want animation when transitioning back to previous view controller.

If you are not using navigation controller, just dismiss you controller like:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In case of navigation controller use this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```